# Нарисовать стрелку на css с возможностью задать маленький бордер

Tags: html, css, css3

Мне нужно нарисовать стрелку. как на картинке (слева сверху)[image]

у меня получилось нарисовать это только так.

```
div {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #f2fbff;
}
div::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  position: absolute;
  top: -16px;
  left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
  background: #f2fbff;
}
div::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 22px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: -19px;
  left: 28px;
  transform: rotate(-46deg);
}
```

Есть способ сделать это проще, не используя два псевдо-элемента?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такой еще вариант. Теперь как на картинке в вопросе.

```css
.blockquote .quote {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  background: aliceblue;
  border: 2px solid lightgray;
  margin: 10px 40px 40px 40px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.blockquote .quote:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 70px;
  top: -20px;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent lightgray lightgray;
}

.blockquote .quote:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 72px;
  top: -15px;
  border: 15px solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent aliceblue aliceblue;
}

.autor {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 50px;
}

.autor img {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.autor {
  padding: 0 0 0 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="autor"><img alt="" src="https://www.stihi.ru/pics/2019/07/30/7939.jpg">
  <p><b>Автор:</b><br>А. С. Пушкин</p>
</div>
<div class="blockquote">
  <div class="quote">Я помню чудное мгновенье:<br> Передо мной явилась ты,<br> Как мимолетное виденье,<br> Как гений чистой красоты.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант с одним псевдоэлементом:

```css
.tip {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 90px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  filter: drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 #000);
}

.tip:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-left: 0;
  background: #f2fbff;
  clip-path: polygon(30px 0, 60px 14px, 100% 14px, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 14px, 34px 14px);
}
```

```html
<div class="tip"></div>
```

Comment: Почему так много людей использует `clip-path` ? Поддержка его без префикса составляет 68% на данный момент, с префиксом 92%

Comment: @MoloF Во-первых я просто продолжил идею ТСа. Во-вторых clip-path хорош тем, что даже если оставшиеся 8% зайдут на ваш сайт, ничего страшного не произойдет, они просто увидят целый прямоугольник вместо обрезанного, самое главное, а именно контент внутри него останется на своем месте. Ну и в случае с неоднородным фоном он прекрасно сыграет свою роль. Можете предлагать свои решения в чем проблема?